# external smtp Plesk 'the server sent an empty reply'

Tags: linux, email, smtp, plesk

Situation:

I got a Domain hosted on "strato.de" and i got a Linux Server hosted by "hetzner.de".

Domain configuration:

```
A Record -> Linux Server IP
MX Record -> Use Strato Intern Mailserver
```

Server configuration:

```
Hostname -> Domainname from Strato
```

---

I used "external SMTP Server in Plesk"

```
Host: smtp.strato.de
Post: 465
Username: **Username**
Password: **Password**
```

my /var/log/mail says

```
Jun 10 07:59:34 **DOMAIN** msmtp: host=smtp.strato.de tls=on auth=on user=info@**DOMAIN** from=**DOMAIN**@**DOMAIN**.de recipients=**RECIP@EXAMPLE.COM** errormsg='the server sent an empty reply' exitcode=EX_PROTOCOL
```

I already installed a fresh Plesk/Linux and I also tried to set the MX record to the Server and tried to use SMTP Server on the Linux. That didn't work either.

---

GOAL:

I want the domain from Strato to point to the Hetzner Linux Server (done A-Record).

I want the emails that the server generates to be sent; I already had this one working but the server sent emails with IP not with the pre-bind Domain. that's bad for GMX because they refuse mails from IP Sources.

Can someone give me advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP):*

I used [this guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7) and installed Postfix manual from SSH console. It is working as it should. I had to Bind the smtp to pot 587 instead of 456 because 456 is only for public signed certificates not for self-signed.

Comment: i have it working now. i found port 587 solution @ friday . emails are working. BUT PHP/Sendmail sends now with parameter -n and thats somehow a bug. cause its a not used parameter but sendmail wont work that way :( i am not @ work for the next 3 weeks :D so i can reply only later

Comment: @KikiTheOne: if you have more detail to add to your solution, feel free to edit this answer (or create a new one if you want attribution, and let me know so I can delete this one). If you have another question however, please ask a new question.

Comment: i will edit ur answer and will mark it as solution as soon as i am back @ work and can provide more detail/questions

Comment: forgot i had this post, cause i fixxed the issue. i reinstalled the Maschine completly and set the hostname to the forwarding Domain. postfix now works, without Errors. 1 ploblem is that i linked 1 Domain of the many to my Server and didnt define a "server-Domain" so now 1 customer Domain is hostname for the complete machine :D but it works so far :D